# Variable does not exist: License__r

Tags: apex, soql

i have the following method:

```
public static AccountForBIView getAssets() {
    List<AggregateResult> assets = 
            [select License__r.Account__c licenseAccountId,License__r.Account__r.Name licenseAccountName, Product2.family productFamily , sum(limit_1_Value__C) sumLimit
                from Asset 
                Where Limit_1_Name__C = 'Users'
                AND License__r.Account__c != null
                AND product2Id != null
                AND product2.Family != 'NONE'
                group by License__r.Account__c,License__r.Account__r.Name,Product2.family 
                LIMIT 100
                ];

    AccountForBIView acc = new AccountForBIView();
    if(!assets.isEmpty())
    {           
        acc.accId = assets[0].License__r.Account__c;
    }
    return acc;
}
```

i get an error on the line

`acc.accId = assets[0].License__r.Account__c;`

the error is

> Variable does not exist: License__r

how can i insert the value of `License__r.Account_c` to an object?

Can i use the alias name to insert to an object? cause i don't know how to insert `sum(limit_1_Value__C)` to an object either

Comment: Add an alais as  License__r.Account__c acc in your query.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm

Comment: And please check the relationship name is correct.Goto the object and check the relationship name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have commented, aggregate queries require the data values to be accessed differently. This is because the aggregate results can contain entirely new values such as your `sum(limit_1_Value__C)` that there needs to be some way to identity. While automatic alias names are generated, it is best to define meaningful names as you have done.

To grab the values you have defined the aliases for, the syntax is very much the same as grabbing values from a map. The `get` method has this signature:

```
public Object get(String alias);
```

so it is up to you to know both the *alias name* and the *type* in your code for each value. The type is coded by adding a cast: the type in round brackets. Essentially you are telling the compiler to expect that type.

So for your example:

```
acc.accId = (Id) assets[0].get('licenseAccountId');
```

A separate point is that you are only using one of the possibly 100 values returned in the query so there is probably a logical problem in the code. If you know there is only ever zero or 1 values `limit 1` would make more sense or if there are multiple values you may be able to select the correct one my adding an `order by` as well as the `limit 1`. Or by making the where term more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can access aggregate values like below

acc.accId = assets[0].get('licenseAccountId');

Comment: You will need an `(Id)` cast too.

Answer (score 0):

acc.accId = assets[0].(Id).get('licenseAccountId');
Do this please.

Comment: Please explain why you are giving an answer rather than just a one liner.  See [answer]